# How to simplify expressions with absolute values in Maple

Tags: maple

For problem `simplify(abs(1-b)+abs(1+b))`, I want maple to take out the `abs` and get results for different ranges of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of your expression to Maple's `piecewise` structure gets you started.

```
restart;

expr1 := abs(1-b)+abs(1+b);

                     expr1 := |b - 1| + |1 + b|

convert(expr1, piecewise, b);

                          / -2 b      b < -1
                          |                 
                         <   2        b < 1 
                          |                 
                          \ 2 b       1 <= b
```

And you can even turn that into a list.

```
PiecewiseTools:-ToList(%);

             [[b < -1, -2 b], [b < 1, 2], [1 <= b, 2 b]]
```

But for either of the above representations you can notice that some of the information is implicit. The `expr1` is identically equal to 2 when `b<1` AND the prior condition(s) don't hold. It's implicit that you also need the negation of the first condition in order to get to the second. Maple handles that by proceeding through the conditions until it gets one that's satisfied, when it evaluates a `piecewise` at a particular point (ie, at a value for `b`).

We can write a procedure to obtain a more explicit (if somewhat redundant) representation.

```
F1 := proc(ee, x::name)
  local T;
  T := PiecewiseTools:-ToList(convert(ee,piecewise,x));
  piecewise(seq([`and`(solve(`and`(seq(`not`(T[j,1]),j=1..i-1),
                                   T[i,1]),{x})[]),
               T[i,2]][],i=1..nops(T)));
end proc:
```

And, using that,

```
F1(expr1, b);

                    / -2 b           b < -1      
                    |                            
                   <   2        -1 <= b and b < 1
                    |                            
                    \ 2 b            1 <= b      

PiecewiseTools:-ToList(%);

       [[b < -1, -2 b], [-1 <= b and b < 1, 2], [1 <= b, 2 b]]
```

Observe the difference between that and what we got before. Now the middle condition explicitly expresses the negation of the first.

We could write another procedure to express `b` in terms of real ranges.

```
F2 := proc(ee, x::name)
  local T;
  T := PiecewiseTools:-ToList(convert(ee,piecewise,x));
  piecewise(seq([x::solve(`and`(seq(`not`(T[j,1]),j=1..i-1),
                                T[i,1]),x),
               T[i,2]][],i=1..nops(T)));
end proc:
```

And, using that,

```
F2(expr1, b);

           / -2 b      b::(RealRange(-infinity, Open(-1)))
           |                                              
          <   2            b::(RealRange(-1, Open(1)))    
           |                                              
           \ 2 b           b::(RealRange(1, infinity))


PiecewiseTools:-ToList(%);

  [[b::(RealRange(-infinity, Open(-1))), -2 b], 

   [b::(RealRange(-1, Open(1))), 2], [b::(RealRange(1, infinity)), 2 b]]
```

Note that those may not each be the widest ranges. We could have alternatively used `solve` to find `b::RealRange(-1,1)` for the second condition, since `2 = 2*b` when `b=1`. The expression is continuous at `b=1` where the second and third conditions meet. And similarly for the other conditions.

```
solve(expr1 = -2*b, b);

                RealRange(-infinity, -1)

solve(expr1 = 2, b);

                    RealRange(-1, 1)

solve(expr1 = 2*b, b);

                 RealRange(1, infinity)
```

A similar thing holds for the inequality results from `F1`. Obtaining these wider results with intervals closed at some ends (or non-strict inequalities) could be done using modified versions of the procedures, to use `solve` instead of just negating all prior conditions at each stage. I haven't done that here.

Let's look at another example, for fun,

```
expr2 := abs(1-c)+abs(1+c)-abs(3-c)-abs(7+c);

           expr2 := |c - 1| + |1 + c| - |c - 3| - |7 + c|

convert(expr2, piecewise, c);

                       /     4          c < -7
                       |                      
                       | -2 c - 10      c < -1
                       |                      
                      <     -8          c < 1 
                       |                      
                       | 2 c - 10       c < 3 
                       |                      
                       \    -4          3 <= c

F1(expr2, c);

                 /     4                c < -7      
                 |                                  
                 | -2 c - 10      -7 <= c and c < -1
                 |                                  
                <     -8          -1 <= c and c < 1 
                 |                                  
                 | 2 c - 10        1 <= c and c < 3 
                 |                                  
                 \    -4                3 <= c

 PiecewiseTools:-ToList(%);

  [[c < -7, 4], [-7 <= c and c < -1, -2 c - 10],

   [-1 <= c and c < 1, -8],

   [1 <= c and c < 3, 2 c - 10], [3 <= c, -4]]

F2(expr2, c);

         /     4          c::(RealRange(-infinity, Open(-7)))
         |                                                   
         | -2 c - 10         c::(RealRange(-7, Open(-1)))    
         |                                                   
        <     -8              c::(RealRange(-1, Open(1)))    
         |                                                   
         | 2 c - 10           c::(RealRange(1, Open(3)))     
         |                                                   
         \    -4              c::(RealRange(3, infinity))

PiecewiseTools:-ToList(%);

  [[c::(RealRange(-infinity, Open(-7))), 4], 

   [c::(RealRange(-7, Open(-1))), -2 c - 10], 

   [c::(RealRange(-1, Open(1))), -8],

   [c::(RealRange(1, Open(3))), 2 c - 10], 

   [c::(RealRange(3, infinity)), -4]]
```

We could plot these results (which I won't inline here).

```
plots:-display(Array([[plot(expr2,c=-8..4),
                       plot(convert(expr2,piecewise,c),c=-8..4)],
                      [plot(F1(expr2,c),c=-8..4),
                       plot(F2(expr2,c),c=-8..4)]]));
```

We could even handle other unknowns, although conversion to `piecewise` might require assumptions.

```
expr3 := abs(1-c) + abs(1+c) - abs(3-c) - abs(K-c):

convert(expr3, piecewise, c) assuming K>1, K<3;

                      /    -3 - K         c < -1
                      |                         
                      | -1 + 2 c - K      c < 1 
                      |                         
                     <  4 c - 3 - K       c <= K
                      |                         
                      | 2 c - 3 + K       c < 3 
                      |                         
                      \    3 + K          3 <= c

F1(expr3, c) assuming K>1, K<3;

                /    -3 - K              c < -1      
                |                                    
                | -1 + 2 c - K      -1 <= c and c < 1
                |                                    
               <  4 c - 3 - K       1 <= c and c <= K
                |                                    
                | 2 c - 3 + K        K < c and c < 3 
                |                                    
                \    3 + K               3 <= c
```

Comment: I could mention that, since the initial conversion to piecewise give a result where the conditions are sorted, one need only negate the immediately preceding condition at each step. And it's easy enough to  "see" the explicit result. I was considering the case where one wants it all done programmatically. And for some piecewise obtained in other ways the set of negations may be required (if the preceding conditions are not sortable, say). But then using `solve` may be nicer, anyway.